# Maximum column difference in two successive rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am working Rails app with PostgreSQL Database. 
I have table Named uploads, which has records like this

```
ID   media_count  created_at
1    10           01-01-2017   
2    12           02-01-2017
3    20           03-01-2017
4    25           04-01-2017
```

I need to find out maximum difference of media_count in any successive rows

Like in above case it will be **8** by difference of these rows

```
ID   media_count  created_at
2    12           02-01-2017
3    20           03-01-2017
```

I have no idea that how to make such query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
Upload.all.each_cons(2).max_by { |x1, x2| x2.media_count - x1.media_count }
```

I assume that successiveness is determined by the `id` column (if it is not, you need to replace the `all` method with an `order` one, providing an explicit column name and ascending sorting declaration, for example, `order(created_at: :asc)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working perfectly.
& and seems that I need to learn about such methods.

Comment: and is there any query way or this is better?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal: yes, there is, but not a pure activerecord one though, you would need to use plain sql at least partially  to achieve this (for constructing either a subquery or a temporary table)

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal: there is a draft of such a query in the editing history if you want to look in this sql direction

Comment: will surely try to understand an work on this, thanks a lot.